# Nginx rewrite rule doesn't work, throws 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

Why this rewrite rule doesn't work? my another rules works flawlessy.
Original link:

```
http://localhost/t.php?gid=1
```

This php file outputs CSS content

I want it to look like this:

```
http://localhost/office/1.css
```

My rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/office/([^/]*).css$ /t.php?gid=$1 last;
```

When i go to:

```
  http://localhost/office/1.css
```

nginx throws 404 error:

```
 [error] 3784#3812: *1 CreateFile() "c:/www/www/office/1.css" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Here's my server block:

http://pastebin.com/jsqPALBJ

Comment: Please, show full server block.

Comment: you set the root in your server block?

Comment: Your rewrite in `location /`, but url `/office/1.css` falls into `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpeg|png|jpg)$`

Comment: @alexeyten oh, silly me, thanks! reply with an answer so i can upvote it :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite in `location /`, but url `/office/1.css` falls into `location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpeg|png|jpg)$`